# How to count the number of columns based on one column from a table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the table in SQL Server. I want to calculate the count of same `ERR_CD` columns based on threshold and insert in a temp table.

| PK_ID | ERR_CD | ERR_THRESHOLD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 5 |
| 2 | 123 | 5 |
| 3 | 123 | 5 |
| 4 | 123 | 5 |
| 5 | 123 | 5 |
| 6 | 123 | 5 |
| 7 | 456 | 2 |
| 8 | 456 | 2 |
| 9 | 789 | 10 |

So my output should be like below eliminating the rows which doesn't meet the threshold.

| PK_ID | ERR_CD | ERR_THRESHOLD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 5 |
| 2 | 123 | 5 |
| 3 | 123 | 5 |
| 4 | 123 | 5 |
| 5 | 123 | 5 |
| 6 | 123 | 5 |
| 7 | 456 | 2 |
| 8 | 456 | 2 |

How can I do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

```
with cte as (
  select * , count(*) over (partition by ERR_CD) cnt 
  from tablename
)

select * from cte where cnt >= ERR_THRESHOLD
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what eshirvana said, so give credit where credit is due. I just wanted to expand on the explanation a bit.

You can use window function like `count` without a `group by` if you have an `over` clause. The result is you'll get whatever the result of the window function would be, replicated over every row to which it is applied.

```
drop table if exists #data
create table #data
(
    PK_ID int,
    ERR_CD char(3),
    ERR_THRESHOLD tinyint
)

insert into #data
values
    (1, '123', 5),
    (2, '123', 5),
    (3, '123', 5),
    (4, '123', 5),
    (5, '123', 5),
    (6, '123', 5),
    (7, '456', 2),
    (8, '456', 2),
    (9, '789', 10)
```

So the first part is to get that count of all rows across each `ERR_CD`

```
select 
    PK_ID,
    ERR_CD,
    ERR_THRESHOLD, 
    CountOfRowsPerErrCd = count(1) over (partition by ERR_CD)
from #data
```

You can see that this gives you the count of errors for each `ERR_CD`, and now all you have to do is write a simple `WHERE` clause to handle that. Unfortunately, you can't use window function directly in a `WHERE` clause, so you have to break out the query above into a subquery or a CTE, and then select from that.

So in its final form you get:

```
;with src as
(
    select 
        PK_ID,
        ERR_CD,
        ERR_THRESHOLD, 
        CountOfRowsPerErrCd = count(1) over (partition by ERR_CD)
    from #data
)
select *
from src
where ERR_THRESHOLD <= CountOfRowsPerErrCd
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using SQL server.

```
with thresold as
(
    select
        pk_id , 
        err_cd , 
        err_threshold , 
        count(pk_id) over(partition by err_cd) as [count] 
    from err
)
select pk_id , err_cd , err_threshold from thresold as a where [count] >= err_threshold;
```